# Is there a way to get .class file from .java file

Tags: java

I have a method that is returning a group of .java files, but I need the .class files of these java files... Is there a simple way to do this?

Here is a sector of the code I'm using to return a list of .java files

```
files = retrieveFiles.listFilesForFolder(folder);
for(File currentFile: files){
     //for each file i need to get the .class file
}
```

Comment: Compile the .java files into byte code with the Java SDK?

Comment: Can't you just check whether the  file name ends with .class?

Comment: @nhahtdh: all the files that are returned are all .java files so no point checking for .class files

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Do you want to compile the Java code from inside Java? Or do you want to find the mapping from .java to .class file generated?

Comment: no i want to test a bunch of java files that all do the same thing(not important why they all do the same thing) with junit and use one junit test to do this so i do not have to write a bunch of tests all the same and i need the .class files to test them

Comment: Are you using an IDE? (eclipse, netbeans, etc.) If so your class files are probably in a different folder to the .java files.

Comment: i dont want to point to .class files because what i want to do will get very messy then, i want to know is there a way to get the .class file of a .java file like file.getClass() or some similar way that is quick and easy

Comment: @flexinIT Please clarify your question. One the one hand side you say, you don't want to know where the .class files are, but on the other hand you say you need them...

Answer (score 2):

Java SDK 6 introduced the Compiler API. That allows to compile java code from within java applications.

Further reading:

- http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/

Comment: Also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158423/compile-java-file-from-within-a-java-program for alternatives if you're using below Java 6.

Comment: I already have my program compiling java files so i dont need to know how to do that but instead of pointing to the .class files from that, i was wondering can you get the .class file a different way incase the user does not compile the file before testing them

Comment: Please clarify on *get the class file*. Is it compiling or is it searching the file system for a matching class file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using OS X or windows, but in either case, you should be aple to use the javac command which compiles .java files and creates .class files.

Then, it's just a matter of figuring out how to run the javac command in your java script, which depends on your os (whether it's unix based or not):
http://www.linglom.com/2007/06/06/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java/

More on the javac command:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html